# SFHFKeychainUtilsErrorDomain error -2000

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mkstorekit, sfhfkeychainutils

The operation could not be completed. (SFHFKeychainUtilsErrorDomain error -2000.)(trouble with password) 
SFHFKeychainUtilsErrorDomain used by MKStorekit.

Answer (score 1):

After much toiling I think I solved this one. It has to do with the way MKStoreKit stores data in the keychain. In your MKStoreKitConfigs.plist, make sure you've added the keys "Name" and "Cost" for your consumables:

[image]

I had initially left the dictionaries empty and I was getting that error. Once I added the Name and Cost key-value pairs, everything worked as expected.

Comment: This was the solution here as well! Thank you very much. However you advise to add "Name" and "Cost" while the screenshot shows "Name" and "Count". The "Count" value is the correct one.